# " But we were unable to locate a matching bytecode (err_code_2)" - can't verify smart contract on etherscan

Tags: remix, etherscan, contract-verification

I deployed my contract to rinkeby recently but I am unable to sell verify it. Here's a screenshot of the page. I've already flattened the file (since I imported like 10 OZ files) via remix, and it complies perfectly via it. I need to verify it so I can test the payable functions, via remix I can't change the payable amounts in comparison to etherscan.

[image]